# Split list of filepaths into sub lists based on sub string in filepath

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a large list file paths pointing to csv files.

```
...SomeFileIDon'tNeed.csv
\001SMPL_1.csv
\001SMPL_2.csv
\001SMPL_3.csv
\001SMPL_4.csv
\001SMPL_5.csv
\001SMPL_6.csv
\002SMPL_1.csv
\002SMPL_2.csv
\002SMPL_3.csv
\002SMPL_4.csv
\002SMPL_5.csv
\002SMPL_6.csv
```

I want to split this list into sub-lists like so

```
[["\001SMPL_1.csv","\002SMPL_1.csv"],["\001SMPL_2.csv","\002SMPL_2.csv"],["\001SMPL_3.csv","\002SMPL_3.csv"],...]
```

This is because I need to combine all similar files into dataframes. So all files ending in _1 will be one df and files ending _2 will be another df, etc.

I wrote code that will split the original list into the sub-lists I want but it's not very efficient. I'm looking for a better way

```
#where f is the original list of file paths
dfs=[]
for i in range(len(f)):
    temp=[]
    for file in f:
        count="_"+str(i)
        if count in file:
            temp.append(file)
    dfs.append(temp)
```

Comment: Is the pattern `_someNumber` always the same, or you need to determine it first?

Comment: It will always end in _someNumber !

Comment: @Gingerhaze are they all `.csv`?

Comment: @alani yes they are all csv files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having in a dictionary like so. It will deal with the "_xx" section no matter how long the ID number gets.

```
paths = ["\001SMPL_1.csv","\001SMPL_2.csv","\001SMPL_3.csv","\001SMPL_4.csv","\001SMPL_4.csv","\001SMPL_4.csv","001SMPL_5.csv"]


split_paths = {}

#iterate paths
for path in paths:
    #get key without .csv
    loc = path.find("_")
    key = path[loc:].replace(".csv","")
    #add to dictionary
    if key in split_paths.keys():
        split_paths[key].append(path)
    else:
        split_paths[key] = [path]

print(split_paths)
```

output:

```
{'_1': ['\x01SMPL_1.csv'], '_2': ['\x01SMPL_2.csv'], '_3': ['\x01SMPL_3.csv'], '_4': ['\x01SMPL_4.csv', '\x01SMPL_4.csv', '\x01SMPL_4.csv'], '_5': ['001SMPL_5.csv']}
```

Then if you really need it in a list.

```
[v for k,v in split_paths.items()]
```

output:

```
[['\x01SMPL_1.csv'],
 ['\x01SMPL_2.csv'],
 ['\x01SMPL_3.csv'],
 ['\x01SMPL_4.csv', '\x01SMPL_4.csv', '\x01SMPL_4.csv'],
 ['001SMPL_5.csv']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done using a combination of regexp parsing to extract the index number, followed by sorting 2-tuples of (index, filename) and then using `itertools.groupby` -- using a key function for `groupby` that returns the index number (see the `lambda` function below).

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

def get_index(filename):
    match = re.search('_(\d+)\.csv$', filename)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(1))
    else:
        return None


def get_filenames_with_index(index_file):
    with open(index_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            filename = line.rstrip('\n')
            index = get_index(filename)
            if index is not None:
                yield (index, filename)


index_file = 'filelist'

dfs = []
for i, files_with_indexes in groupby(sorted(get_filenames_with_index(index_file)),
                                     lambda t:t[0]):
    
    dfs.append([file for index, file in files_with_indexes])

print(dfs)
```

This gives (when `filelist` contains the list shown in the question):

```
[['\\001SMPL_1.csv', '\\002SMPL_1.csv'], ['\\001SMPL_2.csv', '\\002SMPL_2.csv'], ['\\001SMPL_3.csv', '\\002SMPL_3.csv'], ['\\001SMPL_4.csv', '\\002SMPL_4.csv'], ['\\001SMPL_5.csv', '\\002SMPL_5.csv'], ['\\001SMPL_6.csv', '\\002SMPL_6.csv']]
```

(Note: it isn't quite clear here from the question whether you have literal backslashes or escape sequences in your filenames, but whatever you do have will be preserved in the output.)

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
f = ["\001SMPL_1.csv",
"\001SMPL_2.csv",
"\001SMPL_3.csv",
"\001SMPL_4.csv",
"\001SMPL_5.csv",
"\001SMPL_6.csv",
"\002SMPL_1.csv",
"\002SMPL_2.csv",
"\002SMPL_3.csv",
"\002SMPL_4.csv",
"\002SMPL_5.csv",
"\002SMPL_6.csv"]

temp = []
for file in f:
    firstdelpos= file.find("_")
    lastdelpos = file.find(".")
    a = int(file[firstdelpos+1:lastdelpos])
    temp.append([file,a])
sorted_list = sorted(temp, key=operator.itemgetter(1))        
dfs=[]
dupl = []
for i in range(len(sorted_list)-1):
    if(sorted_list[i][1] == sorted_list[i+1][1]):
        if(dupl == []):     
            dupl.append([sorted_list[i][0],sorted_list[i+1][0]])    
        else:
            
            dupl.append(sorted_list[i+1][0])
    else:
        if (dupl==[]):
            dupl.append(sorted_list[i][0])        
        dfs.append(dupl)
        dupl = []
    if(i==len(sorted_list)-2):
                
        if (dupl==[]):
            dupl.append(sorted_list[i+1][0])        
        dfs.append(dupl)
```